# Subsequent presentations of UIAlertController stutter

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uialertcontroller

In a very loaded ViewController in an in-house app I've developed (iPad app written in Swift) for my company, I present alert style UIAlertControllers in a few circumstances.  The first time an alert is presented, it always displays very smoothly.  Any subsequent displays of an alert however end up being very stuttery, even for alerts that don't have much code surrounding their presentation and dismissal.

For example, if the user tries to dismiss the vc without saving after making changes (simple conditional of "if bool_Saved == false { create and display alert }") an alert is presented asking if they're sure they want to exit without saving.  If they choose Yes, the vc is dismissed, otherwise, the alert is dismissed.  The first creation and presentation of the alert animates smoothly, but anytime this conditional or any other code needs to present an alert, the presentation stutters its way through the animation.

The UI on this vc is pretty loaded.  The whole screen is a scrollView with a contentView that contains 10 sub UIViews which in turn each have 3 UITextFields, ~9 UILabels, and ~8 UIButtons (the company wanted an exact digital replica of a paper form they've been using).  Dismissing the vc and reloading it causes the next alert to again display smoothly, but again, subsequent alerts stutter through their present animation.

I've begun profiling in Instruments, but am a bit inexperienced in it and intend to use most of today getting more familiar with the various tools to hopefully find a source for this issue.  What I'd like to know is if anyone has any suggestions on what might be causing this stuttering problem.

Thanks, and please let me know if there's any additional information I can provide.

Editing with code snippet described above:

```
func cancelTapped() {
    if savedOnce == false {
        let alert_Exit = UIAlertController(title: "Exit Inspection?", message: "Unsaved changes to the sheet will be lost upon exit.  Are you sure you want to exit without saving?", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action_No = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil )
        let action_Yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { [unowned self]
            (action) in
            self.exitSheet()
        })
        alert_Exit.addAction(action_No)
        alert_Exit.addAction(action_Yes)

        present(alert_Exit, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        exitSheet()
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the code of your alert?

Comment: Edited the post with the described function that presents the alert.

Comment: Just a guess, but if the user presses no to the first alert, next alert will be displayed quickly, won't it?

Comment: No, the user selecting No in this alert simply dismisses the alert.  I'm using this particular function as an example because the code surrounding its presentation/dismissal is so simple.  Even when I tap Dismiss, thus triggering this alert via the cancelTapped() call, then select No to dismiss the alert, and then give the system a second before tapping Dismiss again, the next alert displayed from cancelTapped() will stutter through its presentation animation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not dismissing the alert. Insert that line in your Yes button.

```
let action_Yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { [unowned self]
        (action) in
        alert_Exit.dismiss(animated: true)
        self.exitSheet()
    })
```

When you create the alert a second time, it probably results in a conflict with previous alert hidden somewhere in your view that wasn't dismissed. How loaded the VC is, it probably doesn't make any difference.

Style `.cancel` will remove itself anyway, whilst `.default` will require you to remove the alert.

Comment: Would this have an affect on going through action_No though?  When I select Yes (action_Yes) to dismiss the VC and then navigate back to the VC, tapping Dismiss and thus calling cancelTapped() results in a smooth alert animation.  Subsequent alert displays with that new VC instance will then stutter..

Comment: No, the .cancel style should dismiss itself, so wouldn't cause delay on subsequent displays. One way to check would be to comment all the animations and see if they are the ones causing the delay. If the number of subviews was an issue, you could probably notice a major difference between an iPhone 5 and a 7 for example, but the way Apple loads the views (what's needed when needed), would make it extremely unlikely to cause any problems.